# How to send POST JSON object with URL?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, url, post

I'm trying to send POST JSON object with URL.

Suppose there are three required parameters for URL in end point. The three parameters are: firstName, lastName, and email.

I constructed the URL address is:

> Blockquote http://url.com/firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@widget.com

Now I build a JSON object.

```
var myObj = {"yadayada": "cool story bro"}
```

I send a JSON object with ajax post to the web service.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://url.com/firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@widget.com", 
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "json", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data: JSON.stringify(myObject), 
    success: function(){}, 
 });
```

The url with parameters are correct, but I get `501 error` not implemented. How do I solve this problem to pass on JSON object with URL parameters to the web service.

Much oblige for your help in advance. I apologize for ajax call not properly formatted, I don't know how to use this website form.

Comment: u want to convert all data to json and want to send right?

Comment: why not sore all informations in the data option like so: `data: $.extend({'firstName':'John','lastName':'Doe','email':'johndoe@widget.com'},myObject)` and the url is simply `http://url.com`. At the moment you send post and get vars, don't you?

Comment: It doesn't work. No, just POST at this moment, but should I do both POST and GET instead?

Comment: Here's a statement from the professor: perform a POST to the URL you constructed in step 1.

What I did in step 1 was GET http://url.com?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&email=johndoe@widget.com

So, is it possible to do both POST and GET to make it work or no?